# How to save SQL Schema Compare options in VS 2012?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, schema-compare

VS 2010 had a way to [save Schema Compare options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833234%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) so that they will be applied to all schema compares.

VS 2012 seems to only persist the options for a single compare; once I close the window, all my options revert back to defaults.

How do I persist SQL Schema Compare options in VS 2012?

**p.s.** I ended up saving a Schema Comparison (.scmp) with my settings, and now I just open that file instead of creating a "New Schema Comparison". It's a shame that the feature from VS2010 did not make it to VS2012.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Take a look at this MSDN thread:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ssdt/thread/3110809b-fa51-485e-91cb-4f530f84c924

> There are no global settings, but you can save a comparison as an
>   .scmp file, which includes your comparison options.  Also, if you
>   create a Schema Compare file from the SQL menu (so it has no selected
>   source or target), set the options you want and then save the file,
>   you can create a template for future comparisons.

Comment: I saved one months ago and wasn't sure if it existed. Read this thread and went to File Explorer and searched for ".scmp" and found it. Double clicked on it and it opened right where I wanted VS 2015

Comment: how can you save such an scmp file in VS 2022 ?