# SSDT Save SqlDataCompare file?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools

Using SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) in Visual Studio 2013 (VS2013)...

When I choose "New Data Comparison..." from the Tools/SQL menu, the resulting "file" is named "SqlDataCompare1" in the title of the window.

It takes a while to specify exactly which tables and columns I want to compare, and which index each should use, and I want to save that setup!

However, I can find no way to save this file!

Is there a way to save a SQL Data Comparison?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now, there is no way to save the Data Comparison in Visual Studio. See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13997014/how-to-save-sql-schema-compare-options-in-vs-2012) also. You can only save Schema Comparison files in `.scmp` format. (I use this to at least save my connections for my Data Comparison)

Comment: Thanks Frank. I hope they add that soon!